# Calculate area $y=2(1-\cos(\varphi))$. Did I calculate correctly?

Tags: integration

How do we calculate the area of a region bounded by $y=2(1-\cos⁡(\varphi)); \; 0 \leq \varphi \leq \pi$.

[image]

I calculate this as:

$\int_0^\pi 2(1-\cos\varphi)\,d\varphi =2\int_0^\pi (1-\cos\varphi)\,d\varphi=2(\varphi-\sin\varphi)\Big|_{0}^\pi=2(\pi-\sin\pi)-2(0-\sin0)=2 \pi$

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Yes, it's fine.

Comment: Yes. You may wish to note that this computation can be made simpler by observing that the integral of $\cos$ (or $\sin$) over any number of complete periods is $0$, which reduces your problem to integrating over a constant.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Maths SX really very useful to me.